# best video format for rasberry pi 4

Tags: video, chromium, kiosk

I want to show videos via Chromium with the Raspberry Pi (Kiosk App for a school) and want to know which Video format is best for this use case.

I did some research and h264 format should be best but is this also the best choice if the Videos are served and embedded in chromium?

The Videos are about 2 Minutes and full screen.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what does `best` mean?

Comment: Best when it comes to performance. So no lagging or hanging up.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.